# .Net Reactor ERROR: Unable to update the dependencies of the project. The dependencies for the object 'PHMateLib.DLL' cannot be determined

Tags: c#, .net, setup-project, net-reactor

I am using .net reactor for code protection when i compile it .net reactor and start my setup project i am not able to build my msi files its throwing compile time error

```
ERROR: Unable to update the dependencies of the project.  The dependencies for the object 'PHMateLib.DLL' cannot be determined.
ERROR: Unable to update the dependencies of the project.  The dependencies for the object 'PHInstallerLib.dll' cannot be determined.
ERROR: Unable to update the dependencies of the project.  The dependencies for the object 'PHMateLogRetriever.DLL' cannot be determined.
ERROR: Unable to update the dependencies of the project.  The dependencies for the object 'PHMateProperties.DLL' cannot be determined.
ERROR: Unable to update the dependencies of the project.  The dependencies for the object 'PHMateService.EXE' cannot be determined.
ERROR: Unable to update the dependencies of the project.  The dependencies for the object 'ProHance.FileHandler.DLL' cannot be determined.
ERROR: Unable to update the dependencies of the project.  The dependencies for the object 'PHMateMoniterServices.DLL' cannot be determined.
```

Answer (score 1):

Often a problem is related to the embedded manifest which can't be read by the installer. In this case "Anti ILDASM" must be deactivation `(-suppressildasm 0)`

by adding `-suppressildasm 0` to the command line options  or unchecking `Anti ILDASM` in GUI